# Saber con que tablas se creo una vista, SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy analizando una base de datos y hay una vista que no se de donde saca la información, hay alguna sentencia para saber de donde saca la vista los datos?

Comment: En la definición de la propia vista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

entra desde SQL Server a la BBDD que quieres mirar y en la sección de vistas busca la que te interese. Haz clic derecho sobre ella y en el desplegable que se muestra haz clic en Diseño.

Se mostrará una ventana de edición de la vista donde aparecerá también las tablas usadas así como la query que se usa para generar esa vista.

EDITO: 
En caso de que quieras obtener la query mediante una query a partir de SQL 2005 puedes obtenerla de esta manera:

```
SELECT definition
FROM sys.objects o
JOIN o.object_id = object_id('dbo.Nombre_DE_La_Vista') and o.type = 'V'
```

Comment: supongo que lo quiere programaticamente  ya que pide "sentencia"

Comment: @lois6b Añadida otra opción!

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte! ☺